# How to get paths for relocatable schemas in Gio.Settings?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gio, gsettings

In Gio.Settings I can list relocatable schemas using

```
Gio.Settings.list_relocatable_schemas()
```

and I can use

```
Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema_id, path)
```

to get a `Gio.Settings` instance. But how can I get all value for `path` that are currently used for a given `schema_id`?

Answer (score 2):

> Normally, a schema has as fixed path that determines where the
>   settings are stored in the conceptual global tree of settings.
>   However, schemas can also be ‘relocatable’, i.e. not equipped with a
>   fixed path. This is useful e.g. when the schema describes an
>   ‘account’, and you want to be able to store a arbitrary number of
>   accounts.

Isn't the `new_with_path` just for that? You have to store the schemas somewhere associated with accounts, but that is not the responsibility of the Settings system. I think `new_with_path` is for the case where your schemas depend on accounts.

I think you can find more information with [GSettingsSchemas](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GSettingsSchema-GSettingsSchemaSource.html) - this is an example in the Description for a case where the Schema is part of a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot do it from Gio.Settings.

I see two options here:

- Keep separate gsetting to store paths of relocatable schemas
- Utilize [dconf](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/%20dconf%20API) API, which is a low-level configuration system. Since there is no Python binding (guessing it's Python question) I suggest using ctypes for binding with C.
  If you know the root path of your relocatable schemas you can use below snippet list them.

  ```
  import ctypes
  from ctypes import Structure, POINTER, byref, c_char_p,  c_int, util

  from typing import List


  class DconfClient:
      def __init__(self):
          self.__dconf_client = _DCONF_LIB.dconf_client_new()

      def list(self, directory: str) -> List[str]:
          length_c = c_int()
          directory_p = c_char_p(directory.encode())
          result_list_c = _DCONF_LIB.dconf_client_list(self.__dconf_client, directory_p, byref(length_c))

          result_list = self.__decode_list(result_list_c, length_c.value)
          return result_list

      def __decode_list(self, list_to_decode_c, length):
          new_list = []
          for i in range(length):
              # convert to str and remove slash at the end
              decoded_str = list_to_decode_c[i].decode().rstrip("/")
              new_list.append(decoded_str)
          return new_list


  class _DConfClient(Structure):
      _fields_ = []


  _DCONF_LIB = ctypes.CDLL(util.find_library("dconf"))
  _DCONF_LIB.dconf_client_new.argtypes = []
  _DCONF_LIB.dconf_client_new.restype = POINTER(_DConfClient)
  _DCONF_LIB.dconf_client_new.argtypes = []
  _DCONF_LIB.dconf_client_list.argtypes = [POINTER(_DConfClient), c_char_p, POINTER(c_int)]
  _DCONF_LIB.dconf_client_list.restype = POINTER(c_char_p)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't**, at least not for an arbitrary schema, and this is **by definition** of what a *relocatable* schema is: a schema that can have multiple instances, stored in multiple *arbitrary* paths.

Since a relocatable schema instance can be stored basically *anywhere* inside DConf, `gsettings` has no way to list their paths, it does not keep track of instances. And `dconf` can't help you either, as it has no notion of *schemas* at all, it only knows about paths and keys. It can list the subpaths of a given path, but that's about it.

It's up for the application, when creating multiple instances of a given relocatable schema, to store each instance in a sensible, easily discoverable path, such as a subpath of the (non-relocatable) application schema. Or store the instance paths (or suffixes) as a list key in such schema.

Or both, like Gnome Terminal does with its profiles:

- `org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList` is a non-relocatable, regular schema, stored at DConf path `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/`
- That schema has 2 keys, a `default` string with a single UUID, and a `list` list of strings containing UUIDs.
- Each profile is an instance of the *relocatable* schema `org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile`, and stored at, you guess... `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:<UUID>/`!

This way a client can access all instances using either `gsettings`, reading `list` and building the paths from the UUIDs, or from `dconf`, by directly listing the subpaths of `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/`.

And, of course, for *non-relocatable* schemas you can always get their paths with:

```
gsettings list-schemas --print-paths
```